# Flutter video player showing blank screen

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-video-player

I wanted to show a video on screen, so I decided to use [video player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin. when I use network videos it works just fine. but when I want to use my assets, the result is just a blank page.
I read the related questions but none of them works for me.

some guy who has the same problem said, that I must use another plugin called [native_video_view](https://github.com/LJaraCastillo/native_video_view). I try to use that but I face many errors.

is there anyone who knows any other solutions?

my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class TrainingDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TrainingDetailScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TrainingDetailScreen> createState() => _TrainingDetailScreenState();
}

class _TrainingDetailScreenState extends State<TrainingDetailScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('video/cliip.mp4');

    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
                  // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
                  return AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                    // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                    child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                  );
                } else {
                  // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
                  // loading spinner.
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Wrap the play or pause in a call to `setState`. This ensures the
              // correct icon is shown.
              setState(() {
                // If the video is playing, pause it.
                if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                  _controller.pause();
                } else {
                  // If the video is paused, play it.
                  _controller.play();
                }
              });
            },
            // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
            child: Icon(
              _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec .yaml:(the video folder is the last one in assets)

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.5.0
  intl: ^0.18.1
  flip_card: ^0.7.0
  appinio_swiper: ^2.0.3
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  audioplayers: ^5.2.0
  video_player: ^2.7.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/img/tab_1.png
    - assets/img/tab_1s.png
    - assets/img/tab_2.png
    - assets/img/tab_2s.png
    - assets/img/tab_3.png
    - assets/img/tab_3s.png
    - assets/img/tab_4.png
    - assets/img/tab_4s.png
    - assets/img/toman1.png
    - assets/img/sp1.jpg
    - assets/img/sp2.jpg
    - assets/img/sp3.jpg
    - assets/img/sp4.jpg
    - assets/img/sp5.jpg
    - assets/img/header_home_quiz.jpg
    - assets/img/animal.jpg
    - assets/img/gaav.jpg
    - assets/img/gav.jpg
    - assets/img/envir.jpg
    - assets/img/sad.png
    - assets/img/happy.png
    - assets/img/cow.jpg
    - assets/img/cat.jpg
    - assets/img/dog.jpg
    - assets/img/duck.jpg
    - assets/img/goose.jpg
    - assets/img/lion.jpg
    - assets/img/wolf.jpg
    - assets/img/mouse.jpg
    - assets/img/hen.jpg
    - assets/img/roster.jpg
    - assets/img/tiger.jpg
    - assets/img/snake.jpg
    - assets/audio/
    - assets/video/
```

and here is my folder root: [root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLkj5.png)

Comment: can you share the error message ?

Comment: there is no error message. its just a blank screen. and i think it has something to do with pubspec or folder root. it can't read the video from my assets.

Comment: well it should've work fine with video_player as you've shared, you can try on different project